# ¿Cómo enviar notificaciones push mediante Firebase-Laravel?

Tags: laravel-5, firebase, push-notification

Tengo realizadas las siguientes configuraciones en mi proyecto, ya subido a un servidor.

//Instalacion

```
composer require alfa6661/laravel-firebase
```

// config/app.php

```
'providers' => [
...
Alfa6661\Firebase\FirebaseServiceProvider::class,],
```

// config/services.php

```
'firebase' => [
'api_key' => env('FIREBASE_API_KEY'),],
```

//Controlador

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Alfa6661\Firebase\FirebaseChannel;
use Alfa6661\Firebase\FirebaseMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;

class NotificacionesController extends Controller
{
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return [FirebaseChannel::class];
    }

    public function toFirebase($notifiable)
    {

           return FirebaseMessage::create()
            ->title('Prueba')
            ->body('Prueba de una notificacion')
            ->data(['id' => $notifiable]);
    }
}
```

Ruta

```
   Route::group(['prefix' => 'ws/'], function()
{
Route::any('notificaciones/{id}','NotificacionesController@toFirebase');
});
```

En la parte `FIREBASE_API_KEY` ya agregue el valor que es. Porque ya tego configurada la aplicacion para que reciba notificaciones. Las notificaciones push unicamente las he podido enviar desde la consola de firebase.

pero necesito enviar una simple notificacion de prueba al celular desde mi proyecto. No se que otros parametros deberia enviar para que me funcione o que otra configuracion me falta.

Comment: Bueno, realmente implementar Firebase en Laravel es muy sencillo y no requiere de paquetes adicionales, aunque no puedo colaborar en esta pregunta porque no conozco este paquete, utilizo Firebase en un par de proyectos Laravel siguiendo la documentación y los ejemplos de Google, sin mayor inconveniente.

Comment: podria proporcionarme  link de la documentacion que te ha funcionado. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Bueno, en la documentación no está explícito, pero está explicado como se debe hacer y como funciona la API, este enlace puede ser útil: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37371990/how-can-i-send-a-firebase-cloud-messaging-notification-without-use-the-firebase a menos que quieras lograr otra cosa.